# Operation timed out using CouchbaseClient

Tags: java, couchbase, timeoutexception, spymemcached

I am getting Timeout exceptions even though there is not much load on the Couchbase server.

```
net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for value
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1003)
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1018)
        at com.eos.cache.CacheClient.get(CacheClient.java:280)
        at com.eos.cache.GenericCacheAccessObject.get(GenericCacheAccessObject.java:55)
...
...
Caused by: net.spy.memcached.internal.CheckedOperationTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation - failing node: /192.168.4.12:11210
        at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:157)
        at net.spy.memcached.internal.GetFuture.get(GetFuture.java:62)
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:997)
        ...30 more
```

This is how I am creating the client.

```
List<URI> uris = new ArrayList<URI>();
        String[] serverTokens = getServers().split(" ");
        for (int index = 0; index < serverTokens.length; index++) {
            uris.add(new URI(serverTokens[index]));
        }
        CouchbaseConnectionFactoryBuilder ccfb = new CouchbaseConnectionFactoryBuilder();
        ccfb.setProtocol(Protocol.BINARY);
        ccfb.setOpTimeout(10000); // wait up to 10 seconds for an operation to
        // succeed
        ccfb.setOpQueueMaxBlockTime(5000); // wait up to 5 seconds when trying
        // to enqueue an operation
        ccfb.setMaxReconnectDelay(1500);
        CouchbaseConnectionFactory cf = ccfb.buildCouchbaseConnection(uris, bucket, "");
        CouchbaseClient client = new CouchbaseClient(cf);
```

I am maintaining a pool of persistent clients in our web server. And we are not even touching the max conn limit which has been set to 15 only.
Pls help me guys in solving this.

Comment: That all appears correct.  Are all of the nodes in the same datacenter?  Which versions are you using?

Comment: @MattIngenthron Yes. All the nodes are in the same data center.couchbase server version is 2.0.0 and java client being used is couchbase-client-1.0.3.jar

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this problem? I'm facing the same issue, with Couchbase 1.8 and Java Client library 1.0.3. This conversation may help: http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/netspymemcachedinternalcheckedoperationtimeoutexception

Comment: I have similar issue with my Couchbase 2.0.1 when I do data intensive data load. I have only 1 client instance. Getting net.spy.memcached.internal.CheckedOperationTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation ... I will start new question.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a backlevel version of Couchbase? 2.0 is very buggy.

Comment: I also faced the same issue.